# add background color to text for a second with a delay

Tags: javascript, function, encoding, var

I have this script that types text itself, then deletes it and type from the beginning. Here is an example https://typedjs.webflow.io

```
<script>
  var typed = new Typed(".typed-words", {
  strings: ["Hello, my name is John."],
  typeSpeed: 75,
  backSpeed: 10,
  backDelay: 800,
  startDelay: 500,
  loop: true,
  showCursor: false,
  cursorChar: "|",
  attr: null,
});
</script>
```

so it shoes the typeSpeed 75. which means that the the phrase "Hello, my name is John." will be typed until the end in 75 whatever units.

question: is there a way to add a background color to the phrase once it finished typing itself?  so let's say the phase "Hello, my name is John." finished typing, its background color becomes blue for a second and the phrase deletes itself and starts typing from the beginning?
Here is an example of this background color change: https://marcusts.com/demo/

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `onStringTyped` method to do this task (I found it from their documentation). You can check my example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<style>
  .last-word {
    color: #299CDF;
  }  
  
</style>
<body>
  
  <div class="typed-words"></div>

  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.11"></script>
  <script>
    console.clear();
    var typed = new Typed(".typed-words", {
      strings: ["Hello, my name is <span class='last-word'>John.</span>", "Hello, my name is <span class='last-word'>Lisa.</span>", "Hello, my name is <span class='last-word'>Beetlejuice.</span>"],
      typeSpeed: 75,
      backSpeed: 50,
      backDelay: 800,
      startDelay: 500,
      loop: true,
      showCursor: false,
      cursorChar: "|",
      attr: null,
      onStringTyped: function(pos, self) {
        const lastWord = document.querySelector('.last-word');
        lastWord.style.background = '#7bfde7';
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh my god you are genius